# HTML Layout - Keep wrapper height 100% even with no content

Tags: html, css

I'm having a small issue with my html layout .

When i have content - it works properly :

http://jsfiddle.net/exqofLft/

but when i have no content . the "wrap" height becomes 0 and the header and footer comes together.

e.g : http://jsfiddle.net/aqgo9370/

When there is no content or little content . i want the header at the top , followed by the full size wrap and the footer at the bottom of the page.

Any ideas how to do this ?

e.g :

[image: img]

CSS :

```
html, body 
{
    height:auto;
    background-color:grey;
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
}

#header
{
    position:absolute;
    width:auto;
    min-width:100%;
    height:75px;
    background-color:yellow;
}

#wrap
{
    position:relative;
    width:auto;
    min-width:100%;
    height:auto;
    background-color:blue;
    margin:75px 0 0 0;
}

footer
{
    position:absolute;
    width:auto;
    min-width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jquery for this.

```
var headerH = $('#header').height();
var footerH = $('footer').height();
var windowH = $(window).height();

$('#wrap').css({
    'minHeight': (windowH - (headerH + footerH)) + 'px' 
});
```

I made some changes in your html/css though.

Check the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/skeurentjes/aqgo9370/9/

Comment: Thanks , works properly . Is there any way to do it without jquery tho ?

Answer (score 2):

By using vw/vh we can size elements to be relative to the size of the viewport. Add the below code in this id `#wrap{}`, [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/aqgo9370/8/)

```
min-height: 100vh;
```

Comment: this is good but it does not use the size of the open window . any way to make it the same height as the browser ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `box-sizing:border-box` , and give it a padding to bottom , and top corresponding to footer and header respectively :

```
 #header
{
    top:0px;
    position:relative;
    width:100%; 
    height:75px;
    background-color:yellow;


}

#wrap
{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:blue;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-top: 75px;
    padding-bottom:50px;

}

footer
{
    position:absolute;
    width:auto;
    min-width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:black;
    bottom:0px;
}
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/exqofLft/4/)**

Comment: good , but does not take the full height of the browser window.

Comment: @Jimmy also note that background-color can be seen through padding area .

Answer (score 1):

Js and position is not needed to Do this. Try this, This is Technically called Sticky footer

```css
html, body {
 height:100%;
    background-color:grey;
 margin:0;
}
#content {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 50px;;/*height of your footer*/
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#header {
 width:100%;
 height:75px;
 background-color:yellow;
}
#wrap {
    width:100%;
 height:auto;
 background-color:blue;
}
footer {
    float: left;
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 background-color:black;
    margin-top: -50px;/*height of your footer*/
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <div id ="header"></div>
    <div id = "wrap"></div>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: Footer will follow the Content height http://jsfiddle.net/exqofLft/8/ i do one small change #content height: 100%; change in to min-height: 100%;

Answer (score 0):

Use `padding-bottom` with desired height like

```
#wrap
{
    padding-bottom:100%;/*or 50% or px value like 50px*/
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: auto;
  background-color: grey;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}
#header {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 75px 0 0 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}
footer {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div>

    <div id="wrap"></div>

    <footer></footer>
```

Comment: But then, when he adds content, that won't do what he wants, presumably.

Answer (score 0):

It's working as it should. Elements always collapse to zero with no content. In order to achieve any height without content, you must assign a height value.

Answer (score 0):

add Minimum height of wrap id 
for example :

```
min-height:500px;
```